# echo text from multiple doms in the same foreach loop with PHP XPatch

Tags: php, dom, xpath

I'm doing a scrapping exercise and it works but I cant think of a way to output the data in the format I want:

```
quote quote quote quote quote : author
quote quote quote quote quote : author
quote quote quote quote quote : author
```

I'm only able to get:

```
quote quote quote quote quote
quote quote quote quote quote
quote quote quote quote quote
author
author
author
```

Code:

```
$html = file_get_contents('http://www.brainyquote.com/authors/buddha');
$dom = new DOMDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML($html);

$classname1="b-qt";
$classname2="bq-aut";
$finder = new DomXPath($dom);
$quotes = $finder->query("//*[contains(@class, '$classname1')]//text()");
$authors = $finder->query("//*[contains(@class, '$classname2')]//text()");


foreach ($quotes as $quote){
    echo $quote->textContent . '<br>';
}

foreach ($authors as $author){
    echo $author->textContent . '<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Based on the current output you get it seems that both arrays have the same number of elements***

So you can do:-

```
foreach ($quotes as $key=> $quote){
  echo $quote->textContent .' : '.$authors[$key]->textContent;
}
```

***if the number of elements are different then:-***

```
$quote_count = count($quotes);
$author_count = count($authors);


if($quote_count > $author_count ){
    foreach ($quotes as $key =>$quote){
        echo $quote->textContent .' : '. $authors[$key]->textContent;
    }

}else {
    foreach ($authors as $key =>$author){
        echo $quote[$key]->textContent .' : '. $author->textContent;
    }
}
```

Comment: I've picked the second answer because it looks cleaner and he posted it before your edit, thanks a lot anyway :) EDIT: Your last edit greatly clarifies the answer.

Comment: @Ricardo  No issue. Also, i have added two solutions you can check now. (I have Edited my code currently)

Answer (score 2):

The main thing to assume is that the two arrays will have the author in the same element of the array as the quote.  So using the key from the quote, you can pick out the corresponding author...

```
foreach ($quotes as $key => $quote){
    echo $quote->textContent . '<br>'.$authors[$key]->textContent. '<br>';
}
```